# jQueryでイベントの処理結果を待つようなループを書きたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

以下のような配列があり、これをループで処理します。

```
var requestTable = ["owner","users","lines","info"];
$.each(requestTable, function(i, val){
    // ループ処理
});
```

その際に、`requestTable`のループではそれぞれサーバーから`GET`でデータを取得します。

```
// ループ処理の中身
$.get("./url...?type="+val, {}, function(data){
    // ここの処理完了を待って次のループに移りたい
});
```

ループ1回ごとに、`$.get()`を呼び出したいのですが、callback処理の完了を待ってから次ループに移りたいのです。というのも、`$.get()`の結果を必要としているためです。

これを綺麗なコードで書きたいのですが、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

---

**追記です。**
`$.Deferred`を使う必要があるという事は分かります。

```
var df = $.Deferred();
//処理
df.resolve();
df.done(function(){
    //処理が終了した時に行う事
});
```

df.done()の中で行うべきところを、次のループ、次のループという具合に繰り返したいという事です。

メソッドチェインにしても良いのかもしれませんが、はじめの配列にある文字列を繰り返し処理したいだけなので、同一処理を繰り返して書きたくありません。

web系の日が浅いため、頭がこんがらがってうまくコード化できません。
申し訳ありませんが、御教示ください。

---

**再追記です**
実行順序を守り、ループごとの実行の終了を待たなければならないのには理由があります。
質問の趣旨に直接関係ないと思い、説明を省いていたのですがループ*n* 回目の結果を使ってループ*n+1* 回目の`$.get()`(実際には`$.ajax()`)のURLパラメータとしたかったのです。
web APIをajaxでたたき、取得したGETデータをもとに次のループでURLを作成して再びweb APIを実行するという再帰処理が必要となっています。
説明不足となってしまって申し訳ありません。

Comment: `同一処理を繰り返して書きたくありません。`とのことですが、繰り返し書いてもよいのでは？と思います。一つ一つの処理が理解できれば、ここの処理はこうすべき、ああすべきと思いつくはずです。そうして修正を繰り返せば、最終的に自分が納得できるコードになると思います。

Comment: 改善したい部分(繰り返しを無くしたい)を質問するのは、Q&Aサイトで至極当然だと思いますので質問者を支持という意味でUpVoteしておきました。

Comment: `$.Deferred`と`Promise`で良いとも思いますが、実行回数が決まっていないのであれば関数でラップして自己を再起するのはいけませんか？

Comment: @ironsand ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Myaku 実行順序、実行回数(`request`にある要素数分)ともに決まっています。またループの結果をまって次のループを処理する必要があるため(`$.get()`で取得した結果を次の`$.get()`のURLパラメータにする必要がある)、コードをどう書けばよいか分からず困っています。
今考えているのは、arrayに入っている`request`のコピーを`$.extend`で作り、そのコピーのarrayを`shift()`して削除してlengthが0になったらループを抜けるのが良いかなと思っています。
ただ、Deferredを使う場合の再帰処理の書き方がよくわからないという状況です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

繰り返しの回数が決まっているのであれば、PromiseとArray.prototype.reduceを組み合わせるのがシンプルです。実装の際は`asyncFunc`をajax処理に置き換えてください。

```js
var requestTable = ["owner","users","lines","info"];

function asyncFunc(api, param){
  var d = $.Deferred();
  console.log(api + ' called with ' + param);
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(api + ' end');
    d.resolve("return value of " + api);
  }, Math.random()*2000);
  return d.promise();
}

requestTable.reduce(function(promise, api){
  return promise.then(function(param){
    return asyncFunc(api, param);
  });
}, $.Deferred().resolve('initial value')).then(function(){
  console.log("complete!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
```

このような非同期処理のチェーンに関してはazuさんの書かれた[JavaScript Promiseの本](http://azu.github.io/promises-book/)が非常に参考になると思いますのでぜひご一読ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
`Array.prototype.reduce`というのがあったのですね、ここで`then`で待たせて`asyncFunc`を実行させるということでしょうか？
とても分かりやすいです！

スニペットもありがとうございます。
順番通りに実行されているようです。

Comment: @tomorin 前の処理の結果を利用したいとのことでしたので、回答に反映しました。

Comment: まさにわたしがやりたい事そのものです！
取得した情報が再帰的に渡されているわけですね。
大変参考になりました。
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

jQueryは直接関係ありませんが、Promiseを使った例を二つほど。

### Promiseをつないでいくパターン

```
var requestTable = ["owner","users","lines","info"];
var promise = new Promise(function(res, rej) { res("init"); });
requestTable.forEach(function(val) {
  promise = promise.then(function(prevData) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      $.get("foo.html",null,function() {
        console.log(val + ": prev is " + prevData + ".");
        res(val);
      });
    });
  })
});
promise.then(function(lastData) {
  console.log("all done. last data is: " + lastData);
});
```

### Promise.all

```
var requestTable = ["owner","users","lines","info"];
var promiseAll = [];
requestTable.forEach(function(val) {
  promiseAll.push(new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    $.get("foo.html",null,function() {
      console.log(val + " done.");
      res(val);
    });
  }));
});
Promise.all(promiseAll).then(function(dataList) {
  dataList.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log("result data: " + data);
  });
});
```

> callback処理の完了を待ってから次ループに移り

という動作をするわけではないですが、目的は果たせるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 説明不足申し訳ありません。
再追記しましたが、*n* 回目の処理結果を使って *n+1* 回目のURLパラメータにするような再帰処理があるため、どうしても実行順序と処理を待ってから次のループを実行する必要があります。

Comment: 「Promiseをつないでいくパターン」ではそのような動作になりますよ？試していないのですか？それともそうならない実行環境がありましたか？
allの方は処理は非同期に実行されるのでできません。ただし結果配列には渡したPromiseの順に格納されます(現状の各ブラウザ上で実施した結果です。仕様はちゃんと調べてません)。